# Render appearing black and white cycles, how to fix?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

My render is appearing black and white in blender. Here is the render: [image: Black and White Minecraft Render]

It should appear in these colors: [image: Colored Minecraft Render]
*Note*: **This is Material Mode, not the actual render**.

Here is the file: [.blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZRPMdT12QJTmF3RG5zSHVkQTg/view)

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please use the https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload .blend files internally. Also, you haven't packed anything into your .blend file, so all the textures are missing resulting in everything turning pink

Comment: Please don't crop your screen captures so tight. You are looking at the blue channel only

Comment: @FreemoX i used mcprep so on my screen it's not pink.

Comment: @LeafyMeap in the future pack your textures so that we don't get that horrible pink all over. https://i.stack.imgur.com/43KPT.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the UV/Image editor, you are looking at the blue channel only, individual color channels get displayed in black and white

Switch to RGBA or RGB view.

[image]

[image]

From the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/image/introduction.html#channels)

> **Draw Channels**
>
> The radio buttons set which channels of the image are displayed.
>
> RGBA
>
> Replaces transparent pixels with background checkerboard, denoting the alpha channel.
>
> RGB
>
> Draw the colored image, without alpha channel.
>
> Alpha
>
> Displays the Alpha channel a gray-scale image. White areas are opaque, black areas have an alpha of 0.
>
> Z-Buffer
>
> Display the depth from the camera, from Clip Start to Clip End, as specified in the Camera settings.
>
> Red, Green, Blue
>
> Single Color Channel visualized as a gray-scale image.

Comment: ok then I'll edit the pic again

Answer (score 2):

First thing I noticed, is that you're probably rendering this in greyscale. To render in colors, make sure your RGB option is selected:

[image]

This will result in an image lite the one you posted. To fix this, make sure you got the RGB selected like so:

[image]

As cegaton mentioned, you are viewing blue hues only, I failed to notice this and edit this answer before cegaton beat me to it. Here's at least a GIF showing what it does (It's all pink because all the textures are missing, but this will work for you)
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm already in RGB, but it's not working :(

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, check out cegaton's comment on your question. It shows how to pack all external information (In this case, your textures) into your .blend files. This would make it easier for you to get help in the future for similar problems

Comment: ok @FreemoX I will